# Grouping together values in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a postgresql database with data having four columns. I am using sqllite3 to run these commands in python. Say the columns are named A, B, c, d. 
Each event in the database is uniquely represented by combined values of A and B. As an example, consider the table below.

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  A| B|   c|   d|
--------------------------------------------------
| 10| 3|  c1|  d1|
--------------------------------------------------
| 11| 4|  c2|  d2|
--------------------------------------------------
| 10| 3|  c3|  d3|
--------------------------------------------------
| 12| 3|  c4|  d4|
--------------------------------------------------
| 13| 1|  c5|  d5|
--------------------------------------------------
| 10| 3|  c6|  d6|
--------------------------------------------------
| 11| 4|  c7|  d7|
--------------------------------------------------
| 10| 1|  c8|  d8|
--------------------------------------------------
| 10| 2|  c9|  d9|
--------------------------------------------------
| 11| 3| c10| d10|
--------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, the combination 10 and 3 appears three times in the table meaning all those rows were part of the same event (where each event is uniquely represented by combined value in A and B). What I want out of this is a list of all the details:

1. grouped according the column A
2. *then* grouped according to it's corresponding value in the column B.

For example, in this case, `(c1, c3, c6), (d1, d2, d6), (c8), (d8), (c9), (d9)` - these correspond to 10 in Column A. The first two 'groups' came from 10 (from A) and the corresponding 3 (from B). The second two came from 10(A) and 1(B), and the last two came from 10(A) and 2(B). Similarly everything else also has to be grouped in this manner.

I am a complete noob to SQL so I am really lost. After much googling I got to this part

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c, ',') c,\
       GROUP_CONCAT(d, ',') d,\
FROM table WHERE GROUP BY A, B
```

This is giving me the details but it groups A and B together and so the output that I get has 10/3 and 10/2 in a different row. I want all the 10s (and all the other values in A) to be grouped together and *then* grouped by it's value in B.

How can this be done? Thanks!

EDIT: The required answer in tabular format-

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  (c1, c3, c6), (d1, d3, d6), (c8), (d8), (c9), (d9)
--------------------------------------------------
| (c2, c7), (d2, d7), (c10), (d10)
--------------------------------------------------
| (c4), (d4)
--------------------------------------------------
| (c5), (d5)
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: For clarity, can you show the desired output in a tabular format?

Comment: Indeed, textual explanation tends to be very hard to understand. Illustrate with data.

Comment: 1. If you have access to PostgreSQL database, why don't run the analytic query there (*before* feeding to python) instead of using sqlite?

2. Do you really want only *one* row per any value of A?

Comment: If column B only ever contains 1, 2, 3 or 4 this can be done. If column B can contain anything you will need some (python) code to assemble the query.

Comment: I updated the question to explain what my desired output is. As to, why I don't run the query before feeding it to python, I could do that but I would still have the same problem right? I don't know how to shape my query.

And I do just want only one row per any value of A. Thanks for the response.